# Why is Fermi-Dirac type of distribution used in semiconductors?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electrons, semiconductor-physics, fermions

We assume that distribution of electrons follows [Fermi-Dirac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics) distribution / statistics in semiconductor model which will help to find the concentrations of electron and holes and the relationship between them. Why is it that we use this distribution?
Why in particular is this distribution used in such models?

Comment: Because they aren't bosons?

Answer (score 1):

Electron and holes are Fermions (particles with spin 1/2). This means that no two particles can share the same microstate. The Fermi-Dirac distribution describes how Fermions fill the available states consistent with this property.

Bosons on the other hand (particles with integer spin) can occupy the same state. The Bose-Einstein distribution describes how bosons fill the available states.